# Difference between simple html img tag running as a server control as opposed to an asp.net Image and security?

Tags: asp.net

If all I want to do is just change an image dynamically, then is an img html tag with the runat="server" attribute sufficient over the asp.net Image control?  My main concern is security.  For example, I am also curious if using html anchor tags with the runat="server" as opposed to the asp.net HyperLink control raises security issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raises what sort of security issues?  If all you want to do is change an image at runtime, an img control running at the server is all you need.  It is simple and does what you need it to do.

Comment: I was asking if it raised any security issues, I wasn't sure.